# length independent sequence classification methods

Tags: deep-learning, classification, long-short-term-memory, sequence-modeling

I am looking to do sequence classification using deep learning. The length of my sequences can vary from a few hundred to several tens of thousands of characters. I was wondering what is a good approach for doing this. I had success with splitting a sequence into subsequences a few hundred characters long and using LSTMs, but then one is faced with the task of putting the results of each of those together and it is nontrivial as well. Any help would be appreciated.